# C++ vectorize double loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, vectorization

I would like to vectorize a double for loop with `omp simd`. My Problem is of the following form:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define N 8000

int main() {
  vector<int> a;
  vector<int> b;
  vector<int> c;

  a.resize(N);
  b.resize(N);
  c.resize(N);

#pragma omp simd collapse(2)
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < c.size(); ++i) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < c.size(); ++j) {
      c[i] += a[i] + b[j];
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile this with `g++ -O2 -fopenmp-simd -fopt-info-vec-all` the vectorization report states:

`note: not vectorized: not suitable for gather load _14 = *_42;`

How can the code be transformed for the compiler to auto-vectorize it?

(Compiler: `g++ 5.4.0`, CPU supports `AVX2`)

**UPDATE**

The main problem is, as mentioned below, a data dependency of `c` whereby only the inner loop seems to be vectorizable. Resolving the dependency, can be achieved by switching the loops as seen below. The compiler auto-vectorized this now for me.

```
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < c.size(); ++j) {
  #pragma omp simd
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < c.size(); ++i) {
      c[i] += a[i] + b[j];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not running with `-O3`?  Have you looked at the disassembly to show that the compiler is not *already* vectorizing your loop?  (It should under `-O3`.)

Comment: First step: lose the `j` loop.  The last iteration overwrites all the work done by lower values of `j`.  The operation implemented is, AFAICT, and adopting Matlab syntax for my pseudocode: `c(1:end) = a(1:end) + b(end)`

Comment: What is the aim of your code? The inner loop dwindles to `c[i] = a[i] + b[N-1];`

Comment: Yes sorry should be `+=` instead of `=` (updated)

Comment: Is the sum given really what you want? As given it is equivalent (modulo rounding errors) to: foreach i c[i] += N*a[i] + B, where B = Sum{ j | b[j]}

Answer (score 3):

the main problem of your code is loop iteration count cannot be computed before executing the loop. you need to replace **c.size()** with **N**.

second problem is if you want vectorize outer loop,statement of **c[i] = a[i] + b[j]** leads to **Flow** and **Anti** dependencies. for ovecome these issues I try to vectorize inner loop and my code successfully being vectorize.

you can read more about Anti and Flow Dependencies in below page: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dependency

I achieve 6.3 speed up  after vectorization.
finally my code looks like below:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
{
        #pragma simd
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; ++j) 
        {
            c[i] = a[i] + b[j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the RAW dependency. I have to disagree with the loop count though. See updated post.